Create break lines in Inkscape
How can I create diagram break lines in an object in Inkscape?  Here are canonical examples of break lines in diagrams:


You could use the Shape Builder tool for something like this.

Draw a shape to use for adding or cutting from the design, and place it over the top

Select all the pieces

Choose the Shape Builder tool, and click on the pieces you want to keep, or click and drag over pieces you want to join


Some examples

